# Manually plotting the 'sheep curve'

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, natural-language

There are a number of 'popular' parametric plots that draw recognisable pictures - of course I must learn more about the 'sheep curve'.

It's straightforward to 'find' them using a natural language query and they are returned as an object which I can then use to generate a plot or an image but how would I go one level deeper and grab the parametric equations and use a `Plot` function directly?

```
curve = ctrl-= sheep curve
(*  Entity["PopularCurve","SheepCurve"] *)
curve["Image"] (* works fine *)
f=curve["ParametricEquations"] (* very long and ugly bunch of trig *)
Plot[f, {\[FormalT,0,2 Pi]}] (* Doesn't work *)
```

I'm close(?), there's something wrong with the parameter being passed to the Plot function but I can't see it.

Comment: Try `f = Entity["PopularCurve", "SheepCurve"]["ParametricEquations"];` and then `ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 2 π}]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how you can find out the info you need to make the plot

[image: sheep]

Consequently, the plot can be made with

```
ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 2 π}]
```

which gives

[image: plot]